# VBA Extract selected dropdown innertext from webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, extract

I'm trying to extract the innertext of a selected dropdown item. The one I'm looking to return is "Institution 2"

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlInstName" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlInstName" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128);">
        <option value="Select…">Select…</option>
        <option value="1867">Institution 1</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="719">Institution 2</option>
        <option value="1971">Institution 3</option>
```

This is what I have but it only returns a 0 value

```
account = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlInstName").getElementsByTagName("selected")(0).innerText
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute selector for `selected`. It is not a tag.

```
ie.document.querySelector("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlInstName [selected]").innerText
```